# How to vectorize this computation of a mask for triplet loss function

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, vectorization

Suppose I have a list of numbers `lst` of length `N`, along with two numbers `epsilon` and `tau`. I want to find the `(N,N,N)` mask matrix `mask` such that `mask[i][j][k]=1` if and only if

`abs(lst[i] - lst[j]) <= epsilon and abs(lst[i] - lst[k]) >= tau`

This is what I tried:

```
d_mat = torch.cdist(lst.unsqueeze(0), lst.unsqueeze(0))
within_eps = torch.where(dmat  <= eps, 1, 0)
over_tau = torch.where(dmat >= tau, 1, 0)

mask = torch.zeros((N,N,N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            if within_eps[i][j] == 1 and over_tau[i][k] == 1:
                mask[i][j][k] = 1
            else:
                mask[i][j][k] = 0
```

So basically I did it naively. Can you show me, with steps, how you come up with a vectorization for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You successfully created the 2d `dmat` of pairwise distances. Now you can use [`torch.logical_and`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.logical_and.html#torch.logical_and) for creating the mask:

```py
mask = torch.logical_and(dmat[..., None] <= eps, dmat[:, None, :] >= tau)
```

If you want to be explicit about the distance computation (and less efficient) you can:

```py
mask = torch.logical_and(torch.abs(lst[:, None, None] - lst[None, :, None]) <= eps,
                         torch.abs(lst[:, None, None] - lst[None, None, :]) >= tau)
```